# How to delete a delete a repositories of github?

Tags: github

I am new to github, I just created many repositories but I can find a way to delete some. So is there any solution to this?

Comment: go to your repository, settings, scroll down, click delete.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project in github and click settings on the tab then at the bottom of the page there is a button that says "Delete this Repository"

Here is an example image:
[image]

Comment: Thank you I had deleted them!